# Slider bootstrap 4 muy largo

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Estoy utilizando el slider o carrusel de bootstrap 4 pero es muy largo en el login, lo que provoca un overflow. He tratado de corregir la altura pero no he podido.

La idea es que el login este fijo y sin la barra de scroll.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que separar el "espacio" del Login de lo que corresponde al carrusel, yo hice algo parecido solo que el login lo posicione del lado izquierdo de la pantalla.

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo respectivo? Solo con imagenes no podemos saber como lo estas implementando

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo parte del código lo mas esencial posible:

```html
body>
        <section class="login-block">
                
            <div class="container">
               <h4 class="titulo"><strong>NOMBRE DEL SISTEMA </strong></h4>
                <div class="row">
                      
        <div class="col-md-4 login-sec">
                    <img src="imagenes/logos/logo.png" width="70%" height="100%" />
                    <hr>
                    <h3 class="text-center">Inicio de Sesi&oacute;n </h3>
                    <form class="login-form" action="xxxx/login.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            
                        <label for="usuario" class="text-uppercase">Usuario</label>
                        <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre de usuario" style="width : 250px; heigth : 1px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contraseña" class="text-uppercase">Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" style="width : 250px; heigth : 1px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                        <small>Recuerdame</small>
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-info" value="Iniciar Sesion" />
                        
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <hr>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 banner-sec">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!-- Indicators -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                        </ol>

                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img  class="d-block w-100" src="imagenes/carousel/ikea1280.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagenes/carousel/books1280.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagenes/carousel/chapter1280.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagenes/carousel/dock1280.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagenes/carousel/peach1280.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagenes/carousel/shelf1280.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                   </div>   
              </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</section>
</body>
```

De esta manera el espacio para el login es fijo, y solo el carrusel es el que esta activo desplazando sus imágenes.

Adapta a tus necesidades, espero te sirva

Saludos

P.D. Este ejemplo esta basado en Boostrap4 para que lo consideres.

Comment: Deberias explicarle al OP que partes se deben cambiar o no para que sea una respuesta valida. Por otra parte, no sabes como tiene implementado el codigo que es necesario para responder

Comment: @Juan Rivera , En base a lo que expone el OP que solo es una imagen y su pregunta, este menciona que  esta basándose en Boostrap 4, creo que le sera útil este código.  Yo pase por el mismo problema al inicio de un proyecto, y este código  me resolvió ese inconveniente.  Solo espero que le sea útil de alguna manera.

Comment: Por favor, [evita contestar preguntas mal formuladas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)